# Rails devise_invitable send invites to multiple emails at once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreach, devise, devise-invitable

I'm trying to create a foreach loop to be able to create invitaion_tokens for each email address added to a text box and send all of the emails.

new.html.erb

```
              <%= simple_form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_invitation_path(), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
               <%= devise_error_messages! %>

              <div class="form-group">

              <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
               <%= f.input :email, :class => "input-txt form-control" %><br />

              <% end -%>

               <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button"), :id => "send-btn", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
              <% end %>
```

invitations_controller.rb

```
  def create
   self.resource = invite_resource

   if resource.errors.empty?
    yield resource if block_given?
    set_flash_message :notice, :send_instructions, :email => self.resource.email if self.resource.invitation_sent_at
    redirect_to root_path
   else
    respond_with_navigational(resource) { render :new }
   end
  end
```

Comment: How do you add the "emails", a string divided by commas? Or are there several text-boxes (one for each email)?

Comment: calling `yield` in a controller? is that some devise magic happening?

Comment: I was going to do a text box where they are divided by commas. Yes, the yield is Devise magic code

Comment: @user3443619 : i have same problem and i am new in rails. So how it is possible to send multiple invitation at a time. How to pass coma separated emails in params ?

Comment: my question is here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099657/send-multiple-invitation-using-devise-invitable-gem-in-rails

Comment: @user3443619 : hey i can help you in this problem because i have similar problem in my web application and i solved it perfectly