# Send multiple invitation using devise-invitable gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-invitable

I want to send multiple invitations at a time using `devise-invitable` gem.

new.html.erb

```
<h2>
    <%= t "devise.invitations.new.header" %>
</h2>
<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div>
        <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
            <p><%= f.label field %><br />
            <%= f.email_field field, placeholder: "Invitation email" %></p>
        <% end -%>
        <%= f.collection_select(:role_id, Role.all, :id, :role_name, :prompt => true)  %>
    </div>
    <p>    
        <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

my controller:-

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
def create
    exit
    if params[:user][:email]== "" || params[:user][:role_id] == ""
        flash[:alert]="Please enter email first and Select any role for invitees"
        redirect_to new_user_invitation_path
    else
        if User.invite!(:email => params[:user][:email], :company_id => current_user.id, :type => 'Employee', :role_id => params[:user][:role_id])
            flash[:notice]="Invitation is send successfully."
            redirect_to new_user_invitation_path
        else
            flash[:alert]="Invitation is not send."
            redirect_to new_user_invitation_path
        end
    end
end
end
```

I think one solution is to pass comma separated emails in invite method but how can I pass it? I really don't know how.

If you have any other solution then please tell me.

Thanks.

Comment: try this `f.email_field :field, "emails[field][]"`

Comment: @Sontya : thanks for reply,
i tried out your solution but it gives me an error "wrong number of arguments"

Comment: Where you get that error..and what you wrote

Comment: @Sontya : thanks, but i have solved my error
thanks for this solution.
it's really worked for me.

Comment: Getting `undefined method "merge" for "emails[field][]":String` any idea?

Comment: Now getting `wrong number of arguments` :(

Comment: @Fdwillis : i explain solution below for your problem.
i think it will help you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i trouble with this problem but finally i got solution to send multiple invitation email at a time.

below i explain my code that how i become possible this.

here is my html view.

new.html.erb

```
<h2>
   <%= t "devise.invitations.new.header" %>
</h2>

<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => invitation_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :post} do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div>
        <% resource.class.invite_key_fields.each do |field| -%>
            <%= f.label field %><br />
            <%= f.email_field field, name: "user[email][]", placeholder: "Invitation email", required: true %></p>

            <div id="createNewTextbox" >
            </div>
            <a id="btnLinkCreate" href="#" onClick="create_new();">
              + INVITE MORE
            </a>
        <% end -%>
    </div>
    <p>
       <%= f.submit t("devise.invitations.new.submit_button") %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

in this i take one text-box by-default with name : "user[email][]" (it is important because using this rails automatically create email array and send in params whene you submit form )

i also generate dynamic text-box using JavaScript and it will create below div when click on invite more link button :

```
<div id="createNewTextbox" >
</div>
<a id="btnLinkCreate" href="#" onClick="create_new();">
  + INVITE MORE
</a>
```

here is my dynamic text-box code of JavaScript.

```
$('#createNewTextbox').append('<input type="email" id="email'+i+'" name="user[email][]" placeholder="Invitation email" required/>');
```

now you can see that i give same name to dynamic text-box (name="user[email][]"), so rails automatically create hash array like this:

```
"user" => { "email" => { "email-1","email-2","email-3"... } }
```

now this hash array is pass in create method in which we fetch every email from params and give it to invite method to send the invitation.

my controller :-

```
class Users::InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
   def create
      params[:user][:email].each do |email|
         User.invite!(:email => email)
      end
   end
end
```

thats it...

if still you have any query then tell comment me.

Comment: Where do you have that JS code? Mine is not triggering

`Uncaught ReferenceError: create_new is not defined...onclick`
&&
`i is not defined`

Comment: my JS code is in assets/javascripts/script.js.
You have to create JS and define "create_new" function in that JS for generate dynamic text-box.
and simply replace this

$('#createNewTextbox').append('<input type="email" id="email'+i+'" name="user[email][]" placeholder="Invitation email" required/>');

to

$('#createNewTextbox').append('<input type="email" id="email" name="user[email][]" placeholder="Invitation email" required/>');

Comment: Is it possible to provide your JS solution?

Comment: function create_new() {
$('#createNewTextbox').append('<input type="email" id="email" name="user[email][]" placeholder="Invitation email" required/>');
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73316/discussion-between-jiggs-and-fdwillis).

Comment: tarkan, sen misin abi?